# How to pass value in OnClick function on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am making a memory game and I want to pass the id of the img with the OnClick value to then store it

```
 <img src={OYOOO} alt={`Image ${i + 2}`} id = {i * 4 - 1} onClick={() => imageClick(id)}/>
```

The imageClick function is built like this :

```
function imageClick(value){
alert("Test");
alert(value)}
```

However, react can't see what I am actually trying to pass, and I get a "id is not defined" error. The id is coming from a loop where I declare a lot of imgs (16) to make a square of img.

Comment: You're not passing any args to `imageClick()`. Perhaps you meant to do `() => imageClick(id)`?

Comment: made a mistakes when writing the question

Comment: Where is `id` declared? Is it supposed to be the same as what you're doing in the alt text? If so you could do `imageClick(i * 4 - 1)`, but it would be better to declare the id elsewhere and then reference it as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` does not exist yet. You could define it outside and use the variable for both props, or use the same calculation :

```
<img src={OYOOO} alt={`Image ${i + 2}`} id = {i * 4 - 1} onClick={() => imageClick(i * 4 -1)}/>
```

Comment: It does not change the error I get

Comment: I was to fast, please see my edit

Comment: Please accepts the answer @furie_noire! Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ref` attribute of the component.

```
import { FC, useRef } from 'react';

export const App: FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
  const img = useRef<HTMLImageElement>(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300" ref={img} id="0835012b-e5e7-42ad-9f85-8222be2583d1" onClick={() => {
        console.log('Image ID: ', img.current.id);
      }} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

You could also extract an `Img` component for reuse:

```
import { FC, useRef } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

export const Img: FC = () => {
  const img = useRef<HTMLImageElement>(null);

  return (
    <img
      src="https://fakeimg.pl/300"
      ref={img}
      id={uuid()}
      onClick={() => {
        console.log('Image ID: ', img.current.id);
      }}
    />
  );
};

export const App: FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Img />
      <Img />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cfir2x?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

Answer (score -1):

It would be helpful if you provide where the id is coming from?

but you can use bind method to preconfigure the function with argument.

```
<img src={OYOOO} onClick={imageClick.bind(null, id)}/>
```

or if you want access to this keyword then,

```
<img src={OYOOO} onClick={imageClick.bind(this, id)}/>
```

example:

```
[{id: 1, src: 'url'},{id: 2, src: 'url'},{id: 3, src: 'url'}].map((image) => {
return <img key={image.id} src={image.src} onClick={imageClick.bind(null, image.id)/>
})
```

Comment: The id is coming from a loop where I declare alot of img like the one in the question, I want to pass the id in the html tag

Comment: use bind method as shown above. there is no need to pass id on html tag.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).